# Automation using an intermediate file

Tags: python, automation

Here is the skeleton of what I am doing

```
#Code PHP
shell_exec("file1.py $args")

#code file1.py
var=sys.argv
..processing..
save to a file.txt

#code file2.py
read from file.txt
..processing..
final output
```

This is working fine, but my concern is if multiple people access the web page simultaneously the intermediate file may be over written. 
Also, Both python files cannot be merged into one.
The data is generated dynamically and needs to be stored somewhere.
Is there a way to prevent over writing or some other way to pass data ?
I tried importing the variable but it doesn't work

Comment: If the same instance is serving multiple clients, you can use synchronisation directives for the file.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use a database? a mysql instance for example. Then your python script could just check this database for new entries and process each via a cron job or something. that way you aren't `shell_exec()`ing either. You could also combine .py 1 and .py 2 into one script and output to another table for retrieval.

Comment: @Nalaurien
I dont know much about mysql so i avoided it, Is there another alternative ?

Comment: yes, you can use other data solutions like the method mentioned by @Coldspeed above, or other flavors of databases out there. But if you have a day or two to dive into it, I'd really recommend becoming familiar with sql. Its safer than what you do here, its faster, is meant for multiuser handling and its really easy once you get the hang of it! There's literally thousands of tutorials about it. Any problem you come across is most likely already answered somewhere. If you still get stuck there are many more people here that can answer a question about it than python script file handling.